# TSQL The multi-part identifier "b.ID" could not be bound. using INSERT OUTPUT SELECT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm not sure why this isn't working, the syntax looks good, but I'm not sure, I have never used this statement before so i maybe doing something wrong.

```
IF @PreCheckPassed = 1 
    --First recreate the lots that where deleted and store the new ID's
    INSERT INTO [tblContainers] ([Name], [FeedLotID])
        OUTPUT INSERTED.[ID], [b].[ID], INSERTED.[Name] INTO @CreatedLots
        SELECT 
            [b].[Name], [b].[FYID] 
        FROM 
            @MergedLots AS [b]

SELECT * FROM @CreatedLots
```

The error occurs on the `OUTPUT` line for [b].[ID]

> The multi-part identifier "b.ID" could not be bound.

What I'm doing is just creating some new records based on a list in the table `@MergedLots` and I'm trying to output the new ID with the `@MergedLots` ID so I can link some other data later.

Any ideas?

Comment: The way it's written implies `@CreatedLots` has two `Id` columns. Can you give the columns in `@CreatedLots`, `@MergedLots` and `tblContainers` and mention which of these have identity columns?

Comment: they all have ID columns, @createdLots has 1 primary key column, and 2 other columns for the data, an INT and a VARCHAR,

Comment: The `OUTPUT` clause of the `INSERT` statement can have only `inserted.column` (columns from the destination table). It can't have columns from the source table. In your example `[b].[ID]` is a column from the source table.

The `OUTPUT` clause of the `MERGE` statement can have columns from both source and destination tables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL Output Clause: How to access the old Identity ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766335/t-sql-output-clause-how-to-access-the-old-identity-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this. It's using `Merge` along with `Insert` :

[Using OUTPUT clause to insert value not in INSERTED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614261/using-output-clause-to-insert-value-not-in-inserted/15614340#15614340)

```
merge into [tblContainers] A
USING @MergedLots AS [b]
on 1=0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
 Insert ([Name], [FeedLotID])
 Values ([b].[Name], [b].[FYID])
OUTPUT 
 INSERTED.[ID], b.Id, INSERTED.[Name] INTO @CreatedLots;
```

This query is not going to be performance friendly. Alternatively, you could have two queries, the first one not considering `b.Id`:

```
INSERT INTO [tblContainers] ([Name], [FeedLotID])
    OUTPUT INSERTED.[ID], INSERTED.[Name] INTO @CreatedLots
    SELECT [b].[Name], [b].[FYID] 
    FROM @MergedLots AS [b]
```

AND a separate `Update` query to update the id

Comment: i was thinking the second method but i decided it was too hazardous, even though the names 'shouldn't' have duplicates in this table i don't want to invite problems :). but i did use the other method.

Comment: Well, if you can't guarantee uniqueness, you'll have to go with the `Merge` option although, chances are, if you need to consider work-arounds like this, you probably need to rework your stored procedure and use of temp tables.

Comment: Im using this to restored deleted records, the original IDS i have but obviously they are no longer on the DB and i need to relink them when i undo the delete. this is just a small part of the whole SP so im just reusing some temporary tables i already have..... its a one off operation so performance is not a concern right now :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the doc at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx, specifically the description of "from_table_name".  I fear you're out of luck; if I read correctly, says it only works for every update statement except INSERT.

Comment: <column_name> ::=  
{ DELETED | INSERTED | from_table_name } . { * | column_name }  
    | $action   is implying that i can use either of the following syntax (DELETED.ID | INSERTED.ID | MyTable.ID) so my syntax should be fine, Aliases are also allowed...... im just wandering whether i need to change the order of the output select or something